# PHP + Elasticsearch - from Elastic2 to Elastic6

Tags: php, elasticsearch, request

Can somebody explain me please the meaning of this query which needs to be translated from Elasticsearch 2 to Elasticsearch 6?

```
$query = '{
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            { "term": { "pouzivatelId": "5b0e65022a35d13df2236183" } },
                            { "term": { "route": "Search:default" } },
                            { "term": { "parametre.hladat": 1 } }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }';


$resp = $this->elastica->request('log/user/_search/exists', Elastica\Request::POST, json_decode($query, true))
    ->getData();
```

I dont understand few things.

1. Url - user. I think it is query to _type
2. Url - exists part. I cant found documentation for this
3. Query - is it compatible with Elastic 6?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. This will work, log is the index, user is the type. Note if you go to es 6.0 you can only one mapping type (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). Also the mappings between 2.x to 6.x change, but this is not your question.
2. use: size=0&terminate_after=1 instead (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking_50_search_changes.html), exists has been removed.
3. No, try this:

   $query = '{
         "query": {
           "bool": {
             "must": [
               {
                 "term": {
                   "pouzivatelId": "5b0e65022a35d13df2236183"
                 }
               },
               {
                 "term": {
                   "route": "Search:default"
                 }
               },
               {
                 "term": {
                   "parametre.hladat": 1
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       }';